# How do I get this loop to iterate back to the line indented right under the while keyword?

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been trying this code, and everything works unless I guess the wrong number, and then it loops back to ask how many sides are on the dice, rather than asking you to guess another number. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random
          
def guessDice():
    
        try:
            numSides = int(input("\nHow many sides are on your dice? "))
            print("\nYour dice is being rolled...")
            while True:
                numGuess = int(input("\nPick a number from 1 to " + str(numSides) + " "))
                randNum = random.randint(1, numSides)
                if numGuess == randNum:
                    print("\nCongrats! You got it!")
                    break
                else:
                    print("\nSorry, you guessed the wrong number! Try again.")

        except ValueError:
            print("\nYou typed in the wrong value. This time, type an integer!") 
guessDice()
```

Comment: Can't reproduce; works fine for me.

Comment: Just a heads up: the singular of "dice" is "die".

Comment: Also, more of an issue: you're RE-ROLLING the die every time the user guesses the wrong value.

Comment: Not sure how it would loop back to the "how many sides" part, given that there is no loop outside of the `try` block...

Comment: You need two while True loops (one for each input).

Answer (score -1):

So `try/except` blocks should be as succinct as possible. Consider rewriting:

```py
import random


# Helper function which verifies that the user input is an integer
def get_integer_input(user_prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(f"{user_prompt}\n > "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input! Please enter an integer!")


def guessDice():
    num_sides = get_integer_input("How many sides are on your dice?")
    print("\nYour dice is being rolled...")
    die_roll = random.randint(1, num_sides)

    while True:
        user_guess = get_integer_input(f"Pick a number from 1 to {num_sides}")
        if user_guess == die_roll:
            print("\nCongrats! You got it!")
            break
        else:
            print("\nSorry, you guessed the wrong number! Try again.")


guessDice()
```

This adds a helper function which verifies the user input and  fixes some issues with your code, most prominently the fact that you were re-generating a random die roll every time the user guessed incorrectly, resulting in what could be potentially an infinite loop if the user continues to guess wrongly (even if you go 1-6 for a 6-sided die, you're re-rolling every guess, meaning it's entirely possible to just keep guessing wrong).

The `try/except` is short and sweet: all it tries to do is cast the user input to an integer, and if it fails, it asks again. If it succeeds, it breaks from the `while` loop, and then the dice-guessing logic happens.

I've also changed the "pick a number" prompt to an f-string so that you don't need to cast and concatenate the user input.

Lastly, I changed "dice" to "die", and converted your variables and functions to `snake_case`, with which Python is conventionally written.

Comment: To reiterate: a `try/except` block should do ONE thing. It's only meant to TRY to do a thing that might fail, and then catch that failure as an exception. NO other logic should be contained in a `try/except` block.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 how so? The error they're describing isn't reproducible, but their code contains other errors. This answer fixes the things that are wrong with OP's code, and makes it behave the way they seem to be expecting.

Comment: If the problem isn't reproducible, you can vote to close the question with that reason.

Comment: This answers the question OP thinks they're asking. Feel free to flag it if you want, but I believe this answer will help OP.

Comment: The code they're trying to debug would be fixed by replacing it with the code they posted. Actually, looking at your answer more closely, I see that on top of doing something substantively different (allowing the user multiple guesses per target, to brute-force a win), your solution loses some input validation and will thus crash if the user makes a non-integer guess.

Comment: OP clearly wants the user to be able to guess multiple times, as evidenced by the "try again" message in their code.